# Does conversion from arrow format to pandas dataframe duplicate data on the heap?

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I'm trying to figure out what's causing high memory usage when reading from an arrow file and converting to a pandas dataframe. When I look at the heap, it seems like the pandas dataframe is almost equivalent in size to the numpy array. Sample heap output from using guppy hpy().heap():

```
Partition of a set of 351136 objects. Total size = 20112096840 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0    121   0 9939601034  49 9939601034  49 numpy.ndarray
     1      1   0 9939585700  49 19879186734  99 pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
     2      1   0 185786680   1 20064973414 100 pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex
```

I wrote a test script to better illustrate what I am talking about, although I'm using a different method to use the conversion, the concept is the same:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
from pyarrow import feather
from guppy import hpy
import psutil
import os
import time

DATA_FILE = 'test.arrow'
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid()) 

def setup():
  np.random.seed(0)
  df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(7196546, 57)), columns=list([f'{i}' for i in range(57)]))
  mem_size = process.memory_info().rss / 1e9
  print(f'before feather {mem_size}gb: \n{hpy().heap()}')
  df.to_feather(DATA_FILE)
  time.sleep(5)
  mem_size = process.memory_info().rss / 1e9
  print(f'after writing to feather {mem_size}gb: \n{hpy().heap()}')
  print(f'wrote {DATA_FILE}')
  import sys
  sys.exit()

def foo():
  mem_size = process.memory_info().rss / 1e9
  path = DATA_FILE
  print(f'before reading table {mem_size}gb: \n{hpy().heap()}')
  feather_table = feather.read_table(path)
  mem_size = process.memory_info().rss / 1e9
  print(f'after reading table {mem_size}gb: \n{hpy().heap()}')
  df = feather_table.to_pandas()
  mem_size = process.memory_info().rss / 1e9
  print(f'after converting to pandas {mem_size}gb: \n{hpy().heap()}')
  return df

if __name__ == "__main__":
  #setup()
  df = foo()
  time.sleep(5)
  mem_size = process.memory_info().rss / 1e9
  print(f'final heap {mem_size}gb: \n{hpy().heap()}')
```

`setup()` needs to be called initially before calling `foo()`.

OUTPUT (from setup):

```
before feather 3.374010368gb:
Partition of a set of 229931 objects. Total size = 3313572857 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0      1   0 3281625136  99 3281625136  99 pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
     1  59491  26  9902952   0 3291528088  99 str
     2  64105  28  5450160   0 3296978248  99 tuple
     3  30157  13  2339796   0 3299318044 100 bytes
     4  15221   7  2203888   0 3301521932 100 types.CodeType
     5  14449   6  2080656   0 3303602588 100 function
     6   6674   3  2018224   0 3305620812 100 dict (no owner)
     7   1860   1  1539768   0 3307160580 100 type
     8    630   0  1158616   0 3308319196 100 dict of module
     9   1860   1  1078064   0 3309397260 100 dict of type
<616 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
after writing to feather 3.40015104gb:
Partition of a set of 230564 objects. Total size = 6595283738 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0     57   0 3281634096  50 3281634096  50 pandas.core.series.Series
     1      1   0 3281625136  50 6563259232 100 pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
     2  59548  26  9905849   0 6573165081 100 str
     3  64073  28  5445176   0 6578610257 100 tuple
     4  30153  13  2339608   0 6580949865 100 bytes
     5  15219   7  2203600   0 6583153465 100 types.CodeType
     6   6845   3  2064024   0 6585217489 100 dict (no owner)
     7  14304   6  2059776   0 6587277265 100 function
     8   1860   1  1540224   0 6588817489 100 type
     9    630   0  1158616   0 6589976105 100 dict of module
<627 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
wrote test.arrow
```

OUTPUT (normal run no setup):

```
before reading table 0.092004352gb:
Partition of a set of 229908 objects. Total size = 31941164 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  59491  26  9902952  31   9902952  31 str
     1  64104  28  5450096  17  15353048  48 tuple
     2  30157  13  2339788   7  17692836  55 bytes
     3  15221   7  2203888   7  19896724  62 types.CodeType
     4  14449   6  2080656   7  21977380  69 function
     5   6669   3  2016984   6  23994364  75 dict (no owner)
     6   1860   1  1539768   5  25534132  80 type
     7    630   0  1158616   4  26692748  84 dict of module
     8   1860   1  1078064   3  27770812  87 dict of type
     9   1979   1   490792   2  28261604  88 dict of function
<605 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
after reading table 3.512406016gb:
Partition of a set of 229383 objects. Total size = 3313510008 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0      1   0 3281625032  99 3281625032  99 pyarrow.lib.Table
     1  59491  26  9902952   0 3291527984  99 str
     2  63952  28  5436848   0 3296964832 100 tuple
     3  30153  13  2339600   0 3299304432 100 bytes
     4  15219   7  2203600   0 3301508032 100 types.CodeType
     5  14303   6  2059632   0 3303567664 100 function
     6   6669   3  2016984   0 3305584648 100 dict (no owner)
     7   1860   1  1539768   0 3307124416 100 type
     8    630   0  1158616   0 3308283032 100 dict of module
     9   1860   1  1078064   0 3309361096 100 dict of type
<604 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
after converting to pandas 6.797561856gb:
Partition of a set of 229432 objects. Total size = 6595149289 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0      1   0 3281625136  50 3281625136  50 pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
     1      1   0 3281625032  50 6563250168 100 pyarrow.lib.Table
     2  59491  26  9902952   0 6573153120 100 str
     3  63965  28  5437856   0 6578590976 100 tuple
     4  30153  13  2339600   0 6580930576 100 bytes
     5  15219   7  2203600   0 6583134176 100 types.CodeType
     6  14303   6  2059632   0 6585193808 100 function
     7   6673   3  2020016   0 6587213824 100 dict (no owner)
     8   1860   1  1540264   0 6588754088 100 type
     9    630   0  1158616   0 6589912704 100 dict of module
<618 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
final heap 6.79968768gb:
Partition of a set of 230570 objects. Total size = 6595283554 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0     57   0 3281634096  50 3281634096  50 pandas.core.series.Series
     1      1   0 3281625136  50 6563259232 100 pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
     2  59538  26  9905349   0 6573164581 100 str
     3  64080  28  5445672   0 6578610253 100 tuple
     4  30153  13  2339600   0 6580949853 100 bytes
     5  15219   7  2203600   0 6583153453 100 types.CodeType
     6   6844   3  2062552   0 6585216005 100 dict (no owner)
     7  14304   6  2059776   0 6587275781 100 function
     8   1860   1  1540264   0 6588816045 100 type
     9    630   0  1159152   0 6589975197 100 dict of module
<627 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

The dataframe seems to have a copy on the heap represented by pd.Series. When the dataframe was first created, it did not have it, only when it was written to the arrow/feather file. Once we read this file, these series return and is ~ the same size as the expected dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does conversion from arrow format to pandas dataframe duplicate data on the heap?

The documentation does a good job at explaining what's happening:  https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/pandas.html#memory-usage-and-zero-copy

In your case the data gets copied indeed. There are some cases where you can get away without copying the data.

But I can't make sense of the output from guppy. For example in the final heap when the arrow table goes out of scope it looks like there are two copies of the data (one in the DataFrame and one in the 57 Series), when really I expect only 3gb.

Comment: yeah I think the thing that confuses me is the guppy output after the function return. I would think at that point the original data would have been deleted at that point. When I re-ran the test with split_blocks=True, self_destruct=True and deleting the table, RSS was ~ 3GB while guppy reported ~6gb. I'm guessing guppy might not be all that accurate. Hard to say

Answer (score 2):

pyarrow, pandas, and numpy all have different views of the same underlying memory.  It appears that guppy is not able to recognize this (I imagine it would be quite difficult to do so).  So it appears to be double counting.  Here is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import psutil
import pyarrow as pa
from guppy import hpy

process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())

# Will consume ~800MB of RAM                                                                                                                                                                                       
x = np.random.rand(100000000)
print(hpy().heap())
# Partition of a set of 98412 objects. Total size = 813400879 bytes.
print(process.memory_info().rss)
# 855588864

# This is a zero-copy operation.  Note                                                                                                                                                                             
# that RSS remains consistent.  Both x                                                                                                                                                                             
# and arr reference the same underlying                                                                                                                                                                            
# array of doubles.                                                                                                                                                                                                
arr = pa.array(x)
print(hpy().heap())
# Partition of a set of 211452 objects. Total size = 1629410271 bytes.
print(process.memory_info().rss)
# 891699200
```